# Programmatically add tier prices

Tags: magento-1.9, products, tierprice

I have a custom module in my magento website where I add products programmatically. I have the requirement to add tier prices to products and I'm using the following code for that.

```
$tierPrices = array(
                    'all_groups'    => '0',
                    'cust_group'    => '2',
                    'price_qty' => '2',
                    'price'   => $post['tprice'],
                    'website_id' => '1'
                 );
$product->setTierPrice($tierPrices);
```

This doesn't add tier prices as expected.

***Edit***

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');               
$product->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) 
        ->setAttributeSetId(14) 
        ->setTypeId('simple')
        ->setWeight(0.50)
        ->setStatus(1)
        ->setTaxClassId(2)
        ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE) 
        ->setStockData(array(
                             'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, 
                             'manage_stock'=>1, 
                             'min_sale_qty'=>1, 
                             'is_in_stock' => 1, 
                             'qty' => 10000 
                           )
                       )
        ->setCategoryIds(array(31));


        $sku =  strtolower($location)."-".str_replace(" ","-",strtolower($data))."-".$i;
        $product->setSku($sku)
                ->setName('test product')                   
                ->setPrice($post['price']) 
                ->setDescription('Test Description')
                ->setShortDescription('description');

  $tierPrices = array(
                'all_groups'    => '0',
                'cust_group'    => '2',
                'price_qty' => '2',
                'price'   => $post['tprice'],
                'website_id' => '1'
             );
  $product->setTierPrice($tierPrices);

  $product->save();
```

A little help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: as expected means ? any error ?

Comment: no.. no errors.. the product is created but without the tier prices

Comment: ca you post your full code here ?

Comment: I have posted the full code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add several tier prices for one product, so you should provide an array of objects (or arrays) to the product.

I didn't try, but I would add an array inside your array, like that :

```
$tierPrices = array(
                ['cust_group'    => '2',
                'price_qty' => '2',
                'price'   => $post['tprice'],
                'website_id' => '1']
             );
$product->setTierPrice($tierPrices);
```

**EDIT**

Here is a working installer code, that created me a test product with the good tier prices. I removed the index "all_groups" from the tierPrices array, because I didn't see it in my Magento. Is it an error ? A custom module ?

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

Mage::app()->setUpdateMode(false);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(1);

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->setAttributeSetId(4)
    ->setTypeId('simple')
    ->setWeight(0.50)
    ->setStatus(1)
    ->setTaxClassId(2)
    ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);


$sku = strtolower("SKU");
$product->setSku($sku)
    ->setName('test product')
    ->setPrice(12)
    ->setDescription('Test Description')
    ->setShortDescription('description');

$tierPrices = array(
['cust_group' => '2',
    'price_qty' => '2',
    'price' => 11,
    'website_id' => '0']
);
$product->setTierPrice($tierPrices);
$product->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: this I have tried, but didn't work for me.

Comment: What is this "all_groups" that you are giving ? I removed it, and tried adding a product, and it worked. See my answer for a working code.

Answer (score 4):

I placed an answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35898106/211029) on the main Stack site, but to avoid a link answer I'll copy it here too. The most efficient,non-direct-SQL method I found was to use Magento's Tier Price API ([Magento 1.X](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductTierPrice/catalogProductTierPrice.html)) as follows:

```
// Build an array of tier level objects
foreach ($tierLevels as $tierLevel) {
    $tiers[] = (object) array(
        'website' => 'all',
        'customer_group_id' => 'all',
        'qty' => $tierLevel['min_qty'],
        'price' => $tierLevel['unit_price']
    );
}

// Use the API to do the update
try {
    $tierPriceApi = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_attribute_tierprice_api_v2');
    $tierPriceApi->update($productId, $tiers);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    // Handle the exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending your needs, here's my solution to update tier price without loading every product. To avoid exception while saving the product, you'll need to set the orig_data of the product before.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('tier_price')->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('eq'=> 1));

    $productsIds = array();

    foreach ($collection->getItems() as $product) {
        $productIds[] = $product->getId();
        $tierPrices[$product->getId()] = array();
    }

    $adapter   = $collection->getConnection();
    $columns   = array(
        'price_id'      => 'value_id',
        'website_id'    => 'website_id',
        'all_groups'    => 'all_groups',
        'cust_group'    => 'customer_group_id',
        'price_qty'     => 'qty',
        'price'         => 'value',
        'product_id'    => 'entity_id'
    );

    $select  = $adapter->select()
        ->from($collection->getTable('catalog/product_attribute_tier_price'), $columns)
        ->where('entity_id IN(?)', $productIds)
        ->order(array('entity_id','qty'));

    foreach ($adapter->fetchAll($select) as $row) {
        $tierPrices[$row['product_id']][] = $row;
    }        


    foreach ($collection->getItems() as $product) {

        $origTierPrice = $tierPrices[$product->getId()];
        unset($origTierPrice['product_id']);
        $product->setOrigData('tier_price', $origTierPrice);

        $product->setTierPrice(array(
            array(
                'website_id'    => '0',
                'cust_group'    => '4',
                'price_qty'     => '24',
                'price'         => '2',
                'delete'    => ''
            )        
        ));

        $product->save();
    }
```