# Magento 2 - Fastest Way to Update Tier Prices Programmatically

Tags: magento2, tierprice

I have below snippet which I am using to update **tier prices** programaticaly:

```
$tierPricenew[0] = array('website_id' => 2,'cust_group' => $groupId, 'price_qty' => 1 , 'price' => floatval($price) );
$productObj->setTierPrice($tierPricenew);
$prices = $productObj->getTierPrice();
$productObj->unsetData('media_gallery');
$productObj->save();
```

This however takes very long with lots of products and so want to just update the `tier_price` attribute alone as suggested elsewhere on stack exchange to quicken the whole process rather than saving the whole product object.

I have tried below methods **saveAttribute**:

```
$tierPricenew[0] = array('website_id' => 2,'cust_group' => $groupId, 'price_qty' => 1 , 'price' => floatval($price) );
$productObj->setTierPrice($tierPricenew);
$prices = $productObj->getTierPrice();
$productObj->setData('tier_price', $prices);
$this->productResource->saveAttribute($productObj, 'tier_price');
```

And this method **updateAttributes**:

```
$tierPricenew[0] = array('website_id' => 2,'cust_group' => $groupId, 'price_qty' => 1 , 'price' => floatval($price) );
$productObj->setTierPrice($tierPricenew);
$prices = $productObj->getTierPrice();
$this->productResourceModel->updateAttributes([$productObj->getId()], ['tier_price' => $prices]);
```

None of the above however seem to work for me. **No errors** are thrown however **tier prices** are not set. They work with other attributes like name etc but not `tier_prices`. Is there a way to update these quickly with methods like above?

I have looked into the `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductTierPriceManagementInterface` class and tried with the remove method here however looking at this just seems to do very similar to my first method and saves the complete product object.

```
$this->tierPrice->remove($product->getSku(), $groupId, '1');
```

Import seems to do this so fast so feel there must be a quicker method to use here.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work for you.

```
 <?php 
namespace Test\Sample\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductTierPriceManagementInterface;

class Index extends Action
{

    protected $tierPrice;

    public function __construct(Context $context, ProductTierPriceManagementInterface $tier)
    {
        $this->tierPrice = $tier;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

     public function execute()
    {
        $sku = 'test-sku'; //Product sku
        $customerGroupId = 2; //Wholsaler group id
        $price = 200;
        $qty = 55;

        $this->tierPrice->add($sku,$customerGroupId,$price, $qty);
    }
}
```

I found the answer at this location [Magento 2: How to set Tier Pricing Programatically Group Wise](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142667/magento-2-how-to-set-tier-pricing-programatically-group-wise)

Comment: This isn't fast. Takes 1 sec to update 1 price atleast in my env. Which is quite slow.