# Update Tier Prices via SOAP API

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2, tierprice

I want to update some tier prices of a product based on a calculation I run. Basically it is printing costs, depending on a price per page, compared to some fixed prices.

I am using the following code to retrieve the old tier prices, do my calculations and replace some prices with the new price:

```
# price for digital printing: 0,066 Euro/per page
define('PPP', 0.066);

# $id is set outside of this, it's a valid product ID
$product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($id);
$data = $product->getData();
$_tierPrices = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_backend_tierprice')->loadPriceData($id, Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());

$dpp = $data['page_count'] * PPP;

$_tierPricesNew = array();

foreach ($_tierPrices as $price) {
    if ($price['price'] > $dpp) {
        $price['price'] = $dpp;
    }

    $price['website'] = '0';
    $price['customer_group_id'] = '0';

    $_tierPricesNew[] = $price;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_tierPricesNew);
```

The result of this, the content of `$_tierPricesNew`, looks fine to me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [price_id] => 2342
            [website_id] => 0
            [all_groups] => 1
            [cust_group] => 0
            [price] => 26.4
            [price_qty] => 1.0000
            [website] => 0
            [customer_group_id] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [price_id] => 2343
            [website_id] => 0
            [all_groups] => 1
            [cust_group] => 0
            [price] => 26.4
            [price_qty] => 5.0000
            [website] => 0
            [customer_group_id] => 0
        )

[...]
```

I am not sure about the additional parameters "website" and "customer_group_id" but they will probably not hurt if present.

When trying to update the prices I run this code:

```
$soap = new SoapClient('https://magento.host/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1');
$session = $soap->login('my_user', 'api_key');

$res = $soap->catalogProductAttributeTierPriceUpdate($session, $id, $price);

$soap->endSession($session);
```

This is basically the [example from the documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductTierPrice/catalog_product_attribute_tier_price.update.html).

And while I can obtain a session ID, so login seems to work, but the result of `$res` is always empty.

Any ideas why this happens? Or how I can debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this running now. I got rid of the API call and instead used a solution [commonly found](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/68201/21431) all over StackOverflow.

My call is now:

```
$product->setTierPrice($_tierPricesNew);
$product->save();
```

I found this to be working without having to run this first:

```
$product->unsTierPrice();
$product->save();
$product->load();
```

Maybe this is no problem for me because I just want to replace some existing prices and not delete (all) the others. So try for yourself if this works for you, too.

I also found something very important [here.](https://magecomp.com/blog/set-tier-price-programmatically-in-magento/) You might need to set:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

At least this was for me the point where it started to work although I did not change anything else to the code. Did not find this in the other code snippets I saw but it was important for my system.